# Drupal theme css not loading on first load

Tags: css, caching, drupal, drupal-7

I have a website that I believe I may be having some cacheing issues with. When I navigate to this site the first time (http://urlgone.com/830e7f/) it will fail to load the theme styles. Once I do a hard reload (F5) the site will load properly and all subsequent loads will load properly. Once I leave the site alone for about 10 minutes, I reload the site and the theme styles are not loading again.

I'm guessing this is either a drupal issue or a server issue, but with my limited amount of knowledge on configuring both, I am at a loss on how to approach this. I've scoured the net to see if anyone has had the same issue to no avail. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: It works just fine, and also, could you please use the actual page url?

Comment: Odd. I also checked on my phone and I still get the same issue (Phone is not connected to wireless so it's not an internal network thing).

Comment: Try going into {admin -> config -> development -> performance} and selecting "aggregate and compress all css files". Did that help?